# Does the sign of the hypotenuse matter in trigonomety

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

[image: SL Loney Trigonometry Page 65]

I came upon this in the book "Trigonometry by SL Loney".My question over here is that why is the sign of the numerators always taken into consideration and that of the denominator is not even thought even though the points P and P' are not in the same quadrant.

Comment: So, given the diagram, everything is clear, yes?  $\theta$ refers to a designated angle and expressions of the form $AB$ refer to the length of the segment $\overline {AB}$.

Comment: Should say, the diagrams are not entirely clear.  In one, for example, $\theta=\angle MOP$ but in another $\angle MOP=\pi-\theta$.  That seems unhelpful and confusing.  It is true, of course, that $\sin (\pi-\theta)=\sin (\theta)$  and so on but that's a claim that requires an argument or at least some discussion. It's always a bad idea to use one variable to denote two different quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign on either the numerator or denominator depends on which side is reflected about the $x$-axis when $\theta$ becomes negative. For $\sin \theta$ and $\tan \theta$ (as well as their reciprocals), by reflecting the right triangle about the $x$ axis you make the opposite side negative, which is why $MP$ is negative.

For $\cos \theta$ (and its reciprocal $\sec \theta$), the adjacent side $OM$ does not change sign because there is no reflection about the $y$-axis. The hypotenuse $OP$ will always be positive.